# How can I flag illegal reputation farming?

Tags: support, reputation, sock-puppets

How can I flag a person who is trying to earn dummy reputation?

Today I have seen 2 people who are doing something along the lines of this: One is asking and the other is answering and vice versa.

How can flag this kind of activity?

Comment: You mean a person has a sock puppet account and uses two accounts, one for asking and one for answering?

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. yes, might be same person with 2 accounts or 2 person knowing each other

Comment: @RRR You don't need to post a comment at each answer, just so you know. It actually clutters less if you don't ;)

Comment: @SimonKlaver thanks for information, i have corrected my mistake.

Comment: @RRR It's not necessarily a mistake, but having only on-topic informative (whether giving or asking information) comments make the world a better place IMO ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Flag one of the posts in question and use the 'Moderator intervention Required' reason, and add some reasoning in there. Mods have tools at their disposal to investigate things like this.

Answer (score 12):

If you are really sure, flag one of the posts of this users with the "in need of moderator intervention" flag. Be sure to write as much as you know as possible. For example:

> I think these users are just asking and answering to farm reputation. They have been doing this at <this>, <this>, and <this> post.

Where every 'this' is a link.

Also, a good thing to check whether you are right: Is the answer of the other user of the pair usually accepted?